# Database Connection Error

Tags: apache-2.2, database, wordpress

Recently this has been happening every so often...say once a day for about 10 minutes. All the pages on my website load up as a blank page with big text DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR.

I try to login to my Phpmyadmin and my login does not work. After 10 minutes or so, my website is back and working, and i can also login to phpmyadmin

My website is a wordpress blog.

It is a dedicated server I am getting from WorldStream.nl

It runs on CentOS 5 with Apache.

I was told to look at logs, failures in logs, but I do not know how to retrieve these logs. My knowledge of SSH is limited to just Logging in and knowing how to restart apache (service httpd restart).

Anyone know what the deal is with my server...why is this happening, what can I do ??

Comment: Time you learnt to find, read and understand your logs then. We can't do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that Error, log in via ssh and try:

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p processlist
```

Enter the password and look at the running processes. If your DB works and you see nothing odd, i would go on with the apache-logs. Try:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

BTW: In many cases phpmyadmin tells you something, if login doesnt work, like "Maximum Connections exceeded". Do you see any message? Do you see a page at all, or an empty page, or does it load until you get connection timeout from the Browser?

Comment: When I tried logging into phpmyadmin, I got the "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" error on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of established database connections from the shell:

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep mysql | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

Try to login from the command line:

```
$ mysql -u root -pPassword
```

Even if the connection limit is reached, you can still login from the database server shell.

If you enabled logging in mysql, you can check the log file `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`.

You can also use `top` to monitor your system processes and `mtop` to monitor your mysql server.